# STS 3.6.3.SR1 and tomcat7

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I'm working with a sts maven java project to implement some web services. When I deploy my war at my test server, I had this error :

```
> Mar 25, 2016 5:01:11 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 25, 2016 5:01:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 820 ms
Mar 25, 2016 5:01:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 25, 2016 5:01:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.28
Mar 25, 2016 5:01:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml
Mar 25, 2016 5:01:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/host-manager.xml
Mar 25, 2016 5:01:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/fs.war
Mar 25, 2016 5:01:12 AM org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1 findType
SEVERE: Compilation error
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFormatException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFileReader.<init>(ClassFileReader.java:372)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1.findType(JDTCompiler.java:232)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1.findType(JDTCompiler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.UnresolvedReferenceBinding.resolve(UnresolvedReferenceBinding.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveType(BinaryTypeBinding.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getTypeFromTypeSignature(LookupEnvironment.java:1188)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getTypeFromVariantTypeSignature(LookupEnvironment.java:1244)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getTypeArgumentsFromSignature(LookupEnvironment.java:1031)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getTypeFromTypeSignature(LookupEnvironment.java:1193)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.createMethod(BinaryTypeBinding.java:507)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.createMethods(BinaryTypeBinding.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.cachePartsFrom(BinaryTypeBinding.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.createBinaryTypeFrom(LookupEnvironment.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.createBinaryTypeFrom(LookupEnvironment.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.accept(Compiler.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.UnresolvedReferenceBinding.resolve(UnresolvedReferenceBinding.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveType(BinaryTypeBinding.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.PackageBinding.getTypeOrPackage(PackageBinding.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getPackage(Scope.java:2283)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ParameterizedQualifiedTypeReference.internalResolveType(ParameterizedQualifiedTypeReference.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ParameterizedQualifiedTypeReference.resolveType(ParameterizedQualifiedTypeReference.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.SourceTypeBinding.resolveTypeFor(SourceTypeBinding.java:1275)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.SourceTypeBinding.fields(SourceTypeBinding.java:614)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.SourceTypeBinding.faultInTypesForFieldsAndMethods(SourceTypeBinding.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.faultInTypes(CompilationUnitScope.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.process(Compiler.java:752)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:464)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:459)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.init(JspServlet.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5026)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5313)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:963)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1600)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> Mar 25, 2016 5:01:13 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig
> deployWAR INFO: Deploying web application archive
> /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/javi.war Mar 25, 2016 5:01:13 AM
> org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processAnnotationsJar
> SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry
> [com/sun/glass/ui/Accessible.class] from Jar
> [jar:file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar!/] for
> annotations
> org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid
> byte tag in constant pool: 18     at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:131)
>   at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:60)
>   at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:209)
>   at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:119)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2049)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1931)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1899)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1885)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1281)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:855)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:346)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5172)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:963)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1600)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I'm using Spring Tool Suite 3.6.3.SR1 java8 and tomcat7. 
Any help please !?

Comment: What exactly version of the Tomcat are you using?

Comment: Apache Tomcat/7.0.28

Comment: Try to use a more recent version of Eclipse ECJ lib. And make sure you use JDK instead of JRE